# Should chicken be seasoned before vacuum sealing?

Tags: chicken, food-preservation, vacuum

I am going to vacuum seal then freeze several pieces of chicken breast. Is there a benefit to putting anything on it before I vacuum seal? For example I normally put spices on, but not sure if doing so before storing would have a benefit. Also if I decide to marinade, it wouldn't really work with the vacuum sealer as it would suck all the juice out. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: very closely related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3446/using-a-vacuum-sealer-to-marinate?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

There's no benefit to seasoning before you seal your food unless you plan to cook the food in the bag once it's thawed, as in sous vide. Salting or spicing isn't going to make it last longer in the fridge, and it's not going to impart much in the way of flavor either.

I suppose seasoning and rubbing your spices on before freezing would save you a bit of time later if you had a specific recipe in mind for the chicken, however if you decided to use the chicken for a different purpose you'd have to clean all that off and re-season/spice it if you did.

Comment: Perhaps just one exception to all this should be noted: spiced oils you just brush on. At least the vacuum sealers I know about won't totally remove those, and them staying on longer does (in my experience at least) indeed make a difference.